# Docusign REST API Variable Page Contract Signature

Tags: docusignapi

I've ran into a bit of a snag with the docusign API that I'm assuming has to be a common issue. I have a variable page pdf that is generated via BIRT for a service agreement. The signature page contains regions that can be matched on successfully using IDR in the GUI interface and appropriately applies the template on the correct page when using the GUI.

I'm assuming the IDR capabilities do not exist in the docusign rest API?

When I send over a composite template with a copy of the PDF and select the same template it always adds the signature boxes on the first page (instead of page the correct page ex. pg 44). Pretty much like it doesn't do the partial page matching. Is there someway to turn on page IDR for composite templates?

If not could I somehow send over multiple pages as separate composite templates than specify to con-cat these separate documents into a single document?

Answer (score 0):

At appears that adding more items to the array compositeTemplates does indeed concatenate the pdf files. I'm still unsure why IDR does not work the same thru the rest API, but with this I should be able to at least complete the task I need to do.

```
{
   "emailSubject": "Composite Template Test",
   "enableWetSign": false,
   "status": null,
   "templateRoles": [
      {
         "email": "test@test.com",
         "Name": "Test Customer",
         "roleName": "Customer",
         "clientUserId": null,
         "defaultRecipient": null,
         "accessCode": null
      },
      {
         "email": "test@test.com",
         "Name": "Test Company",
         "roleName": "Company",
         "clientUserId": null,
         "defaultRecipient": null,
         "accessCode": null
      }
   ],
   "compositeTemplates": [
      {
         "serverTemplates": [],
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": 1
            }
         ],
         "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "filename.pdf"
         }
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "2",
               "templateId": "MY TEMPLATE ID"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates": [],
         "document": null
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem getting more than one set of documents to be accepted in one composite template.  Without knowing any details, since you're generating the document did you consider placing a "white text" anchor on it so you can simply assign signature tags that way?